# JSON deserialization in scala - use default value if field doesn't exist

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I am deserializing a json to a class in scala.
If the class has a member which doesn't exist in the json, I would expect it to get the default value assigned in the primary constructor, but that is not the case.

In the example bellow, how can I get prop2 to be an empty string (right now it is null).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

case class Thing(var prop1 : String = "",
                var prop2 : String = "",
                var prop3 : String = "")



object test {

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val thingStr = """{"prop1":"val1","prop3":"val3"}"""
    val thing = mapper.readValue[Thing](thingStr)
    System.out.println(thing)
  }
}
```

The above code prints

```
Thing(val1,null,val3)
```

how can I get prop2 to be an empty string?

Comment: I don't think this a scala problem, my guess it's this is the default behavior of Jackson. If that's the case, you'll probably need to define a custom object mapper.

Comment: It is not supported - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom deserializer as suggested by Diego.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.{Version, JsonParser, JsonGenerator}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

case class Thing(var prop1 : String = "",
                var prop2 : String = "",
                var prop3 : String = "")



object test {

  val module = new SimpleModule("CustomJson", Version.unknownVersion())
  module.addDeserializer(classOf[Thing], new ThingDeserializer)


  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.registerModule(module)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val thingStr = """{"prop1":"val1","prop3":"val3"}"""
    val thing = mapper.readValue[Thing](thingStr)
    System.out.println(thing)
  }
}

class ThingDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer[Thing] {
  def deserialize(jp: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext) = {
    val node : JsonNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    System.out.println(node)
    new Thing(prop1 = if (node.has("prop1")) node.get("prop1").toString else "",
      prop2 = if (node.has("prop2")) node.get("prop2").toString else "",
      prop3 = if (node.has("prop3")) node.get("prop3").toString else "")
  }
}
```